# What would it look like if we broke the speed of sound underwater?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, acoustics, shock-waves

Would anything special happen as we approach the speed of sound? Would there be a sonic boom?

Comment: You get cavitation way before that. Breaking the speed of sound in water would require going at almost 1500m/s, which only a kinetic penetrator can do for a very short distance. The fastest supercavitating torpedoes are essentially rockets that move trough a gas bubble they create on their own: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VA-111_Shkval, but even they are short by a factor of four.

Comment: It's probably not possible to  break the sound barrier under water.  The drag forces involved increase with the square of the velocity.  At 1500 m/s, the forces would no doubt be large enough to destroy the projectile.

Comment: @CuriousOne , I took a quick look at the article.  Those torpedoes are short by a factor of 15.

Comment: It may be impossible to actually do it, but it would nevertheless be interesting to determine if it is theoretically possible and, if it is, what it would look like.